# Can't set height 100% on floated element

Tags: html, css

I've managed to position two divs next to each other by using the following code however my left div won't allow a `height: 100%` and seems to be defaulting to auto, how can I set the height to 100% with my current setup?

CSS:

```css
.left_div {
  width: 30%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.right_div {
  word-wrap: break-word;
  float: left;
  width: 65%;
  margin-left: 15px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

HTML:

```html
<div class='panel-body thread-body'>
  <div class='panel panel-default original-post-panel'>
    <!-- dynamically generated content -->
    <div class='panel-body'>
      <div class='left_div'>
        <!-- dynamically generated content -->
      </div>
      <div class='right_div'>
        <!-- dynamically generated content -->
      </div>
      <div style="clear:both">
        &#160;
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Height of the floating divs doesn't goes up to the parents.
2. Thus, the height of the parent div will be 0.
3. Thus, the height of your left div will be also 0 if its height is set to 100%.
4. Thus, the content of your left div will overflow, and it will be visible only because of this overflow.

The simplest solution for your problem would be if you would put an empty div with `clear: both` after all of them:

```
<div class="left_div">...</div>
<div class="right_div">...</div>
<div style="clear: both">&#160;</div>
```

Effectively, it will be a similar effect as if you would start an empty "new-line" (despite there is *no* textual line rendering here).

Comment: I see what you're saying, hasn't seemed to have fixed the issue - might be to do with my html, ill update my question with the full html

Comment: @joe I doublechecked, and found that it had to. There is probably some other problem there, too. I suggest to start your first steps with the firebug addon of the firefox.